# Asserting array values in spark column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

df.show yields this:

```
[scalatest] +-----------------------------+----+----+-------------------+
[scalatest] |deserializedBlob             |a   |b   |c                  |
[scalatest] +-----------------------------+----+----+-------------------+
[scalatest] |[2,2.1,2021-01-02 00:00:00.0]|2   |2.1 |2021-01-02 00:00:00|
[scalatest] |[1,1.1,2021-01-01 00:00:00.0]|1   |1.1 |2021-01-01 00:00:00|
[scalatest] |[null,null,null]             |null|null|null               |
[scalatest] +-----------------------------+----+----+-------------------+
```

I'm trying to assert that the `deserializedBlob` column contains those rows, so I tried this:

```
df.filter(array_contains(col("deserializedBlob"), Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 00:00:00.0"))).count shouldBe 1
```

but this errors out with

```
[scalatest] - should test *** FAILED ***
[scalatest]   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(`deserializedBlob`, TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01 00:00:00.0'))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be an array followed by a value of same type as the array members;;
[scalatest] 'Filter array_contains(deserializedBlob#38, 1609459200000000)
[scalatest] +- Project [deserializedBlob#38, a#45, b#46, c#47]
[scalatest]    +- Project [deserializedBlob#38, fields_90688278_1d0e_47b8_a821_b555d78649ac#41, fields_90688278_1d0e_47b8_a821_b555d78649ac#41.a AS a#45, fields_90688278_1d0e_47b8_a821_b555d78649ac#41.b AS b#46, fields_90688278_1d0e_47b8_a821_b555d78649ac#41.c AS c#47]
[scalatest]       +- Project [deserializedBlob#38, deserializedBlob#38 AS fields_90688278_1d0e_47b8_a821_b555d78649ac#41]
[scalatest]          +- Project [method(StructField(a,IntegerType,true), StructField(b,DoubleType,true), StructField(c,TimestampType,true), binaryblob#34) AS deserializedBlob#38]
[scalatest]             +- SubqueryAlias data
[scalatest]                +- Relation[binaryblob#34] customtype
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:268)
[scalatest]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:279)
```

Even if this worked, it isn't optimal for me since I want to make sure that the column contains the entire row array, like `[2,2.1,2021-01-02 00:00:00.0]`.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The column `deserializedBlob` is of type struct not array.

Comment: Its type is struct, check the schema and access the value individually.